# Regexp which will search symbol from class A, but not from class B?

Tags: perl

I'm newbie in Perl regexp programming (using it in .NET RegExp class), so for more than a day im trying to create regexp which will search symbol from class A (for example class `\W`) but not from class B (for example class `[']`). Other words, pattern `\W+` matches `d'sparil!` in position 1 on `'`, but i need pattern `???` which matches `d'sparil!` only in position 8 on `!`. And if there are some other `\W` chars like `%`, `@`, `(`, this pattern will skip only class B `[']` chars. Have any idea? I have tried silly pattern like ``` [\W^'``]+ ``` but it works strange… if it works at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
/[^\w']/
```

since `\W` is `[^\w]`.